# How to slice some fileds in aggregation query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate poems-collection. Each poem has "lines" files which is array of lines like

```
lines: [
    {
        id: '123'
        text: 'ABC'
    },
    {
        id: '567'
        text: 'AKA'
    },
    {
        id: '890'
        text: 'ZXZ'
    }
...
]
```

```
db.getCollection('poems').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "languageId": "en",
            "published": { $exists: true, $ne: false }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "userId": "$userId"
            },
            "lastPoem": {
                $last: "$$ROOT" // take just last document alternatives $first or $push (all)
            },
            "count": {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { 'lastPoem.publishedDate': -1 } },
    { "$skip": 0 },
    { "$limit": 10 }
])
```

I need to slice number of "lines" to 5 for example.
How do I use slice in this case with aggregation?

I tried to put different places, but did not get it to work.

```
{ "lastPoem.lines": { "$slice": [ "$lines", 10 ] } }
```

Thank you!

Comment: @varman That's factually incorrect, [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) was introduced in version 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lines` field is inside `lastPoem` it should `$lastPoem.lines` and you have used just `$lines` in `$slice`,

- `$addFields` after `$group` stage and before `$sort` stage

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      "lastPoem.lines": {
        $slice: ["$lastPoem.lines", 5]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w48w1MAml42)